# How to create dummy XML structure?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I need dummy XML for the below code, there is `if (reader.NodeType == //XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name.ToLower() == "transmissions") condition so`.

```
     public BusinessEntities.FileParseResult Parse(string FilePath)
     {

        FileParseResult _fileParseResult = new FileParseResult();
        _fileParseResult.FileParseResultType = FileParseResultType.ValidFileClaim;


        Logger.LogMessage(PREPROCESS_FILEPARSER.TRACE_MSG, "****WorkComp.Net : Pre Processor -> Start parsing valid AT XML File *****");
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath, settings))
        {
            try
            {
                string tranmissionsattr = string.Empty;
                string header = string.Empty;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name.ToLower() == "transmissions")
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
                        {
                            reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                            tranmissionsattr = tranmissionsattr + "  " + reader.Name + "=\"" + reader.GetAttribute(i) + "\"";
                        }
                        reader.MoveToElement();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<transmissions />` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<transmissions attribute1="test1" attribute2="test2" />
<transmissions attribute1="test1" attribute2="test2" />
<transmissions attribute1="test1" attribute2="test2" />
<transmissions attribute1="test1" attribute2="test2" />
```

:)

Comment: Won't work if transmission is root tag.  You can only have one root tag.

Comment: @jdweng if the conformance level is set to fragment (it is), then it will work fine.  Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) *"This setting accepts XML data that has multiple root elements or text nodes at the top level."*

Answer (score 0):

Here is some test code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BusinessEntities be = new BusinessEntities();
            be.Parse(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class BusinessEntities
    {
        public enum FileParseResultType
        {
            ValidFileClaim
        }
        public class FileParseResult
        {
            public FileParseResultType FileParseResultType { get; set; }
        }
        public BusinessEntities.FileParseResult Parse(string FilePath)
        {

            FileParseResult _fileParseResult = new FileParseResult();
            _fileParseResult.FileParseResultType = FileParseResultType.ValidFileClaim;


            //Logger.LogMessage(PREPROCESS_FILEPARSER.TRACE_MSG, "****WorkComp.Net : Pre Processor -> Start parsing valid AT XML File *****");
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><transmissions version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"workcomp.net/wcn2/public\"><transmission><header></header><reports><report><R4>FL</R4><R5></R5>JCN<R15>ClaimTest1</R15></report></reports><trailer recordcount=\"1\"/></transmission></transmissions>";
            StringReader sreader = new StringReader(xml);
            Console.WriteLine(xml.Substring(195,10));
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sreader, settings))
            {
                try
                {
                    string tranmissionsattr = string.Empty;
                    string header = string.Empty;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name.ToLower() == "transmissions")
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
                            {
                                reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                                tranmissionsattr = tranmissionsattr + "  " + reader.Name + "=\"" + reader.GetAttribute(i) + "\"";
                            }
                            reader.MoveToElement();
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string error = e.Message;
                }
            }
            return _fileParseResult;
        }
    }
}
​

​
```

Comment: Thank you for Response. 

string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><transmissions version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.workcomp.net/wcn2/public\"><transmission><header></header><reports><report><R4>FL</R4><R5></R5>JCN<R15>ClaimTest1</R15></report></reports><trailer recordcount=\"1\"/></transmission></transmissions>";

Problem is :

 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml , settings))
when my debugger hitting to above line it is giving me an error 

Illegal characters in path.

i can not provide physical path for XML.

Comment: The closing tag </re‌​ports> has an invisible illegal character.  Copy and paste the tag in this comment which doesn't have the invisible character.